# How to add PyPi dependencies to DEB package

Tags: python, installation, distutils, deb, autobahn

I created some `python` app using `autobahn` and packaged it using `baazar builddeb`. In python setup.py file I added `requires` tag with all the required dependencies. Is it possible to tell debian package installer to install these packages?

I added some of deps to `debian/control>Depends` but:

1. `dpkg -i my_package` does not install dependencies. Just shows the error and I need to install these deps manually.
2. some packages does not exists in standard Ubuntu repos. For example autobahn. And in general I'd like to have installed all python dependencies by `pip/easy_install`

I am using `DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup` with personalized `install` action. So I think I could run `easy_install packages` there. Is it good idea?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mix different packaging systems.
Probably the cleanier way would be to include these dependencies to the .deb, so that they they ship with your program.

Comment: `dpkg -i` does not attempt to install required or depended packages.  You will need to install using `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

Answer (score 11):

Create debian packages from pypi using the python-stdeb package, then depend on them like any other package.

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb

Comment: Alternatively, use fpm: https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm. It can also build rpm or solaris packages from python packages.

Comment: See also: [Pybuild](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Pybuild), a new, amazing tool from Debian that supersedes `stdeb`.