# How do I package a deb file for my python3 project?

Tags: python-3.x, debian, packaging

I've created a python3 application which is dependent on,

```
python3
dateparser
```

python3 is easy enough for a deb to automatically resolve, but dateparser is installed via pip.

How can I package my deb when my dependencies come from 2 different sources?

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210389/how-to-add-pypi-dependencies-to-deb-package

Comment: That does help, thanks